# PDO Use MySQL's NOW()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How would I use MySQL's `NOW()` in PDO prepared statements, or how would I workaround using it while keeping in mind that possibly the Apache Server and Database Server might have either a slightly current time mismatch (few seconds), or in rare occasions might be timezones apart?

I have the following function in my code:

```
try {
    $dbh->insert("users", array(
        "email" => $email,
        "password" => $password,
        "salt" => $salt,
        "ingame" => $ingame,
        "kiosk" => $kiosk
    ));
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    error($ex);
}
```

Which calls:

```
/**
 * Inserts data into a table. Data must be given in key-value pairs.
 * 
 * Example: $dbh->insert("table", array(
 *                                  "data1" => $data1,
 *                                  "data2" => $data2
 *                                  );
 * 
 * @param type $table   The table to insert to
 * @param type $keyvaluepairs   The key-value pairs.
 * @return type The statement that this query produced.
 */
public function insert($table, $keyvaluepairs) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (";
    $values_sql = ") VALUES(";
    $values = array();
    foreach ($keyvaluepairs as $key => $value) {
        $sql .= "`${key}`, ";
        $values_sql .= "?, ";
        $values[] = $value;
    }
    $query = substr($sql, 0, -2).substr($values_sql, 0, -2).")";
    return $this->query($query, $values);
}
```

Which calls:

```
//TODO update documentation to show it also handles associative arrays with bindvalue
/**
 * Can be called to create a query. Use either unnamed or named placeholders for the prepared statements.
 * 
 * Example: $dbh->query("INSERT INTO table (data1, data2) VALUES(?, ?)", array($data1, $data2));
 * 
 * @param type $query   The input query, including unnamed or named placeholders
 * @param type $values  The input values. If it's not an array, then it will be an one-element array
 * @return type The statement constructed by this query
 */
public function query($query, $values = array()) {
    if (!is_array($values)) {
        $values = array($values);
    }
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $i = 1;
    if (is_assoc($values)) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $statement->bindValue($key, $value);
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $statement->bindValue($i++, $value);
        }
    }
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

Where I have the function:

```
function is_assoc($array) {
    return (bool)count(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_string'));
}
```

So the deal here is that I cannot use custom `MySQL` queries for the inserts as I've encapsulated those for the sake of easyness, but I still want to be able to insert `NOW()` *without* making use of `TIMESTAMP` / `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

I hope you understand that this question requires an explained answer as I have already read the 'normal' answers and shown that they do not satisfy my needs.

**UPDATE:** I have added `const SQL_NOW = 1;` to my `DBH` class, however now I want to modify the `insert` to something like this:

```
public function insert($table, $keyvaluepairs) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (";
    $values_sql = ") VALUES(";
    $values = array();
    foreach ($keyvaluepairs as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == SELF::SQL_NOW) {
            $sql .= "NOW(), ";
        }
        else {
            $sql .= "`${key}`, ";
            $values_sql .= "?, ";
            $values[] = $value;
        }
    }
    $query = substr($sql, 0, -2).substr($values_sql, 0, -2).")";
    return $this->query($query, $values);
}
```

Which may be a suitable solution, **however** I cannot use `1` as `SQL_NOW` value, as it would then fail if I'd want to insert an integer `1`. If I go with this solution, what value would `SQL_NOW` then have? Is it even possible to give it *no value*?

Answer (score 3):

Excellent question!

This is a perfect example that clearly shows why **all these numerous `insert(), update()` and all other stuff, intended to substitute SQL, are wrong by design**.

NOW() is not the only issue you will face with. Just because *SQL is not that silly a language* as it seems at first glance. And it was invented on purpose. And it's reliability was proven for decades. Means it is not that easy to write whole SQL just as an exercise while learning PHP.

So, the best thing you could do is **to keep SQL as is.**

What you really, really need is a helper function or two. To automate the repetitive tasks. That is ALL. While SQL have to be left as is. Which will let you to use ALL it's power including use of functions, **functions with arguments(!)**, query modifiers, such as 'INSERT IGNORE' or extended syntax like JOINS.

In case you are using PDO, it is not that simple but feasible.

However, the only proper solution is to use a **placeholder of the special type** for the SET statement.

```
$data = array(
        "email"    => $email,
        "password" => $password,
        "salt"     => $salt,
        "ingame"   => $ingame,
        "kiosk"    => $kiosk,
);
$dbh->query("INSERT INTO ?n SET reg = NOW(), ?u","users", $data);
```

Just one single line to solve all that mess and many, many, many other issues.
Just one single `query()` method to run any query you want, even `REPLACE INTO`.

Update.

## Just look what are you doing!

You were planning your class to *simplify* things. But at the moment you are making it more and more complex. In the end you will have a hulking giant which inconsistent syntax for the numerous exceptions scarcely understood even by it's creator and noone else. And which *still* don't let you run some queries.

Please rethink your design before it's too late.

Comment: I might be stubborn, but I think that using **only** `insert()` I do not intend to write functions for other functionality is easier for the trivial inserts, and `NOW()` is a trivial value to be inserted. I do agree though that every other functionality should not be rewritten. I've also added my own 'solution' (with a bug) to the question, I'd appreciate if you could answer that aswell.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a wrapper that does this if you pass it an additional argument containing all the column=>SQLfunction values you need.

Mine looks like this:

```
function pInsertFunc($action, $table, $values, $sqlfunctions)
{

    global $pdb;

    // There's no way to pass an SQL function like "NOW()" as a PDO parameter,
    // so this function builds the query string with those functions.  $values
    // and $sqlfunctions should be key => value arrays, with column names
    // as keys.  The $values values will be passed in as parameters, and the
    // $sqlfunction values will be made part of the query string.

    $value_columns = array_keys($values);
    $sqlfunc_columns = array_keys($sqlfunctions);
    $columns = array_merge($value_columns, $sqlfunc_columns);

    // Only $values become ':paramname' PDO parameters.
    $value_parameters = array_map(function($col) {return (':' . $col);}, $value_columns);
    // SQL functions go straight in as strings.
    $sqlfunc_parameters = array_values($sqlfunctions);
    $parameters = array_merge($value_parameters, $sqlfunc_parameters);

    $column_list = join(', ', $columns);
    $parameter_list = join(', ', $parameters);

    $query = "$action $table ($column_list) VALUES ($parameter_list)";

    $stmt = $pdb->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($values);

}
```

Use it like this:

```
$values = array(
    'ID' => NULL,
    'name' => $username,
    'address' => $address,
);

$sqlfuncs = array(
    'date' => 'NOW()',
);

pInsertFunc("INSERT INTO", "addresses", $values, $sqlfuncs);
```

The query string that results looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (ID, name, address, date) VALUES (:ID, :name, :address, NOW())
```

Comment: And another day I will need to call a function with user-supplied data, like INET_ATON(:ip). This approach of yours is a road to nowhere.

Comment: It's a convenient helper function.  It automates some repetitive tasks.  That's all.  I find it useful.  It doesn't prevent me from using the full power of SQL when I need it.

Comment: Not to mention it is awfully prone to sql injection.

Comment: It's only prone to SQL injection if you're allowing the user to define the keys in $values, which you can see I'm not doing here.  All of the values in $values will be passed safely through to the database, with no risk of SQL injection.